# How do I disable "Show_desktop"?

Tags: 11.10, compiz, desktop-background

In order to have a different wallpaper on each work space in 11:04,i needed select my wallpapers in Compiz, then disable "Show_desktop"using gconf-editor. in 11:10, this option is not available.

Is there any work around?

Answer (score 6):

Nautilus in Oneiric is using gsettings and not gconf, you can use this:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have dconf-tools installed, run dconf-editor. Find org>gnome>desktop>background. There is an option show-desktop-icons.

Now, by default it looks unchecked. But this is not true! You need to click it once to check it, and then the second time to uncheck it. The name of the option (show-desktop-icons) itself must be written in bold now (this shows that now it is not by default, but manually chosen), and it should still be unchecked (as it was by default).

If now you select the Wallpaper plugin in ccsm, you will see your chosen wallpapers.

P.S. Since 11.04 I have a shortcut to switch between the two: run ccsm, select Commands plugin, copy/paste to command0:

```
bash -c 'if [ "`gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons`" == "false" ]; then gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons true; else gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false; fi'
```

scroll down to run_command0_key and select you favorite key combination. Make sure that the Commands plugins is selected. Now, whenever you press the key combination it will switch between showing your desktop icons or four different wallpapers (with no icons).